# Concatenation of Strings and lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following python script, it converts the Celsius degree to Fahrenheit but I need to join two list with strings between and after them

```
Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
fahrenheit = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Celsius)
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in Celsius)+" in Celsius is "+''.join(str(i) for i in fahrenheit )+" in farenheit"
```

The outcome is this(not what i wanted):

```
39.2
36.5
37.3
37.8 in Celsius is 102.5697.799.14100.04 in farenheit
```

How can I achieve this:

```
39.2 in Celsius is equivalent to  102.56  in fahrenheit
36.5 in Celsius is equivalent to  97.7  in fahrenheit
37.3 in Celsius is equivalent to  99.14  in fahrenheit
37.8 in Celsius is equivalent to  100.04  in fahrenheit
```

**EDIT SORRY MY BAD**
Well, the original code I had was

```
def fahrenheit(T):
    return ((float(9)/5)*T + 32)
def display(c,f):
    print c, "in Celsius is equivalent to ",\
          f, " in fahrenheit" 
Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
for c in Celsius:
    display(c,fahrenheit(c))
```

But due to reasons I need it to be **within 3 lines**

Comment: _Hint_: look at the first operation in your print line, it says to join `Celsius` with a newline character, so that is exactly what Python does. Same for the last operation, you asked Python to join the Fahrenheit values. Now you know the problem, so you can try to fix it yourself. **Being able to solve this on your own will empower you to solve future code quandaries.** Usually I try to break it down to the simplest step. How can you just print the first pair of values? `print '%f in Celsius is equivalent to %f in Fahrenheit' % (Celsius[0], fahrenheit[0]`. Now try `join`. _Hint_: use `zip()`

Comment: 3 lines? Is this some sort of code golf? If so you're at the wrong site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 lines:

```
>>> Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
>>> msg = '%g in Celsius is equivalent to %g in Fahrenheit'
>>> print '\n'.join(msg % (c, (9. * c)/5. + 32.) for c in Celsius)
```

yields:

> 39.2 in Celsius is equivalent to 102.56 in Fahrenheit
>   36.5 in Celsius is equivalent to 97.7 in Fahrenheit
>   37.3 in Celsius is equivalent to 99.14 in Fahrenheit
>   37.8 in Celsius is equivalent to 100.04 in Fahrenheit

Comment: Could you explain your print line? I do not see where the c is coming from

Comment: sorry, copy and paste issue, this is just [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296134/1020470) by [@jcusick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4202958/jcusick) refactored a little

Comment: okay i see. This is a smart way of doing the same thing without using lambda. I have not thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It's probably easiest to do the formatting as you go:

```
Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
def fahrenheit(c):
    return (float(9)/5)*c + 32

template = '{} in Celsius is equivalent to {} in fahrenheit'
print '\n'.join(template.format(c, fahrenheit(c)) for c in Celsius)
```

**EDIT**

If you really want it under 3 lines, we can inline the `fahrenheit` function:

```
Celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]    
template = '{} in Celsius is equivalent to {} in fahrenheit'
print '\n'.join(template.format(c, (float(9)/5)*c + 32) for c in Celsius)
```

If you don't mind long lines, you could inline `template` as well and get it down to 2 lines...

However, there really isn't any good reason to do this as far as I can tell.  There is no penalty for writing python code that takes up more lines.  Indeed, there is generally a penalty in the other direction that you pay every time you try to understand a really long complex line of code :-)

Comment: You could also use `((9 * x) / 5) + 32` and avoid the call to `float()` as all the temperatures are floats

Comment: +1 for using function instead of lambda when the lambda is not in internal anonymous function (_ie_: ie: not necessary) - I think pylint, pyflakes or pep8 warns against this, but can't remember.

Comment: @Andrew -- I'd personally go with `(9. * x) / 5 + 32` since within a function, you don't want to necessarily _assume_ that all the inputs aren't `int` -- But I wrote it this way to try to keep things as consistent with OP's code as possible.

Comment: @depperm -- Thanks for fixing that up for me :-)

Comment: @mgilson interesting. Are `float(9)` and `9.` doing the same thing "under the hood" as it were?

Comment: Do you think its possible to keep it within 3 lines? I am trying to get that you see

Comment: @mgilson no problem

Comment: @mgilson I appreciate your prompt response and efficient answer. Even though it is the most efficient, Chris's answer was what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the way you feel, then @Kode.Error404 you should accept Chris' answer by clicking the green check mark so he gets the credit. You can still upvote mgilson's answer too.

Comment: @Andrew -- The result is the same.  `float(9)` constructs (or more likely fetches) and `int` and then constructs a float from it.  `9.` constructs (or more likely fetches) the float straight away.  In either case, you're left with a float with the value of 9.

Comment: @Kode.Error404 -- Feel free to choose whichever answer was most helpful for you.  As the question asker, the checkmark power is yours and nobody has any right to tell tell you to check one answer over another.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do it with `join`, you can include the extra parts of the string inside of the `join` statement.

```
celsius = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
fahrenheit = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Celsius)
print '\n'.join(str(i) + " in celsius is " + str(j) + "in farenheit" for i, j in zip(celsius, fahrenheit))
```

Comment: This would have been my suggested answer except that using lambda this way IMO is kind of a code smell, and so I didn't want to encourage it.

Comment: @Mark I don't love it either, but mgilson already took the right way to do it ;)

Comment: @Kode.Error404 Were you referring to the extra `)`?  It's fixed now.

Comment: @ChrisMueller Thanks! I am learning python and hence practising the different ways to achieve the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You could always try formatting using %f for float numbers and placing the output in a loop:

```
for i in range(len(Celsius)):
    print '%f in Celsius is equivalent to %f in fahrenheit' % (Celsius[i], fahrenheit[i])
```

EDIT: As per the suggestion of @mgilson, using `zip` would be better to use instead of taking a count of just `Celsius`:

```
for c,f in zip(Celsius, fahrenheit):
    print '%f in Celsius is equivalent to %f in fahrenheit' % (c,f)
```

Comment: You're better off using `zip`:  `for c, f in zip(Celsius, Fahrenheit): ...`

Comment: And then why not use a list comprehension too with `str.join()` the way like in [the other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296366/1020470) answer. _IE_: `print '\n'.join('%f in Celsius is equivalent to %f in fahrenheit' % (c,f) for c,f in zip(Celsius, fahrenheit))`